# Are glucosamine tablets actually effective in building up cartilage in joints?

Tags: supplements, joints

Glucosamine is quite popular and is featured prominently in pharmacies and supermarkets in Australia.

I was once recommended by a GP to take glucosamine tablets to reduce joint soreness as I exercise quite regularly and occasionally have joint soreness.

Is there any evidence (peer reviewed papers etc.) that glucosamine actually works to built up cartilage in joints?

My personal experience was I didn't notice any perceivable difference.

Comment: it's not FDA approved either. its just like any other suppliments.

Comment: I'm not sure about actually building up cartilage, but I have heard more support for the idea that it helps prevent further cartilage loss.

Comment: I talked to a reputable orthopedic surgeon about this, his answer was "We are not sure it works, but there is some evidence and it can't hurt."

Comment: I am using glucosamine and hydrolyzed collagen since I get osteoarthritis in my knee, because of extreme sports like longboarding and skateboarding. I can tell that the first day of take a 10g of collagen, I felt something weird inside my knee. Like something was putting me electroshocks inside my knee. Six months later, I am still using both but I had to quit extreme sports and take my bicycle to commute from home to work. Somehow my life changes, at 32 years old, makes you realize that life is only one.

Comment: I also never noticed any difference, but it didn't hurt anything either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I head to NIH if I want non biased supplementation information. The problem is that it almost always has to do in the context of disease, so [their write-up seems to be effective in the context of Osteoarthritis](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/druginfo/natural/807.html):

> Osteoarthritis. Most research on
>   glucosamine sulfate has measured its
>   effectiveness on osteoarthritis of the
>   knee. However, there is some evidence
>   that it might also help osteoarthritis
>   of the hip or spine.
>
> Some research suggests that
>   glucosamine reduces pain of
>   osteoarthritis in the knee about as
>   well as the over-the-counter pain
>   reliever acetaminophen (Tylenol). It
>   also seems to reduce pain about as
>   much as the nonsteroidal
>   anti-inflammatory drugs (NSAIDs)
>   ibuprofen (Motrin, Advil) and
>   piroxicam (Feldene). But there is a
>   difference between glucosamine sulfate
>   and these drugs in the time it takes
>   to reduce pain. The NSAIDs, such as
>   Motrin, Advil, and Feldene, relieve
>   symptoms and reduce pain usually
>   within about 2 weeks, but the
>   glucosamine sulfate takes about 4-8
>   weeks.
>
> Glucosamine sulfate does not seem to
>   decrease pain in everyone who takes
>   it. Some people get no benefit. Some
>   research shows that glucosamine
>   sulfate might not work very well for
>   people with more severe, long-standing
>   osteoarthritis, or for people who are
>   older or heavier.
>
> In addition to relieving pain,
>   glucosamine sulfate might also slow
>   the breakdown of joints in people with
>   osteoarthritis who take it long-term.
>   Some researchers hope that glucosamine
>   sulfate might keep osteoarthritis from
>   getting worse as quickly as it
>   otherwise might. There is some
>   evidence that people who take
>   glucosamine sulfate might be less
>   likely to need total knee replacement
>   surgery.

When I want to know things related with sports, I use the British Journal of Sports Medicine, keep in mind most of the content is behind a paywall. Fortunately [this study on glucosamine](http://bjsm.bmj.com/content/37/1/45.full?sid=f6e2453b-e5fe-4c09-80fb-6e09a4bcd989) is not:

> glucosamine supplementation can
>   provide some degree of pain relief and
>   improved function in persons who
>   experience regular knee pain, which
>   may be caused by prior cartilage
>   injury and/or osteoarthritis. The
>   trends in the results also suggest
>   that, at a dosage of 2000 mg per day,
>   the majority of improvements are
>   present after eight weeks.

Comment: +1 for telling how you find answers instead of directly answering the question.