# Snapping/cracking in joints when moving

Tags: joints

I love indoor climbing. It happened a few times that I caught a handgrip in a particularly bad way and now when I move my wrist a snapping sound is heard.

It does not hurt, everything seems alright. It's just the sound does not sound really naturally. Is there something I can do to get rid of it?

Comment: I would try [glucosamine](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/183/are-glucosamine-tablets-actually-effective-in-building-up-cartilage-in-joints?rq=1), having used it before for a short while, it took away the snap crackle and pop during my use of it.

Comment: Anyone care to explain what is -1 for?

Comment: They should explain... it wasn't me.  People here generally aren't comfortable with injury / physical therapy questions, because most people don't feel they can responsibly answer them over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Its impossible for us to give you precise advice - this could be OK, or it could be a sign of a growing injury.

if you grabbed a hold wrong, and now your wrist is behaving oddly (popping in a specific position), I'd take it as a sign that you have a very mild injury / overuse, and to take a couple nights / a week off and see if it gets better.  Maybe you should also climb a little lower grades / less strenuous routes for a little while.  Continuing to train on it may be OK, or it may make it worse, there's no real way for us to know out here on the internet.

Supplements and taping with athletic tape both sometimes get recommended, but I've never had them work for me.  Sometimes there's no substitute for proper rest.